# (c++ win32) Window not showing up despite it running

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I was trying to subclass a button but my window isn't showing up and I have to restart visual studio every time to run the application. At the moment nothing shows up : it just shows nothing when I run the application. I think it's something to do with the function RegisterClass1.Please help

Here is my code:

```
// CustomButton.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "CustomButton.h"
#include "SkinClass/skin.h"
#include <commctrl.h>
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
const char g_szClassName[] = "MyClassName";

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void                RegisterClass1(HINSTANCE);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_CUSTOMBUTTON, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    //MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    RegisterClass1(hInstance);










    // Perform application initialization:
    /*if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }*/
    /*HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);*/

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_LAYERED, g_szClassName, "Scenes", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);



    CSkin aa(IDR_CR, ID_CIRCLE);
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);

    HWND hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("START EDITING!"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, ((rect.right - rect.left) / 2) - 90, 500, aa.Width(), aa.Height(),
        hWnd, (HMENU)NULL, NULL, NULL);




    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CUSTOMBUTTON));





    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);










    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    aa.Destroy();
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_CUSTOMBUTTON));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_CUSTOMBUTTON);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: RegisterClass1()
//
//   PURPOSE: Registers the class
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//
//
//

void RegisterClass1(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    WNDCLASSEXA wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.lpszMenuName = "MENU";
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;


}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC hdc_x = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
        HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_CIRCLE)); //Load the bitmap
        HBITMAP holdbmp;
        holdbmp=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc_x, hBitmap); //Put the bitmap into the hdc_x
        SelectObject(hdc_x, holdbmp);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 180, 50, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //Draw it.
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdc_x);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
















//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

If I don't restart the laptop, visual studio gives me this message :
Error   LNK1168 cannot open C:\Users\Rubel\source\repos\CustomButton\Debug\CustomButton.exe for writing CustomButton    C:\Users\Rubel\source\repos\CustomButton\CustomButton\LINK  1

Comment: `case WM_CREATE: case WM_COMMAND: ` doesn't look like a terribly good idea. You'll need Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) if you want to take out the guesswork.

Comment: That was the default code visual studio gave out. So there was no reason why I should've been neg repped .

Comment: No, it wasn't. A default project runs, and certainly does not contain this sequence of code.

Comment: I meant the case WM_CREATE: case WM_COMMAND: and that was given out by visual studio .

Comment: No, it wasn't. There is no `WM_CREATE` case label in a default generated Windows desktop application. You added it, and you did it wrong.

Comment: Yes, there was! I did not add anything

Comment: A fallthrough from `WM_CREATE` into `WM_COMMAND` is meaningless. There has not been a single release of Visual Studio, throughout its history, where the wizard generated that section of code. Incidentally, I created a Windows Desktop application just today, and the code does not contain a `WM_CREATE` case label. That's Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I can create a video of me making a win32 application using the wizard and it will give you that code!

Comment: If the first comment did not solve your problem, then you probably do not understand your code. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: Well, I did follow your advice and added {} around that case and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please, be conducive and not making accusations at me what I did and what I didn't do.

Comment: I gave a minimal reproducible example. It's not my fault that you can't reproduce in your set up.

Comment: It's neither minimal nor complete. You are loading accelerators from a resource, but haven't provided the resource script. So that makes it incomplete. Chances are, that the accelerators aren't required, and that keeps it from being minimal. Why is there `InitInstance` which you never call? Why is there `MyRegisterClass` which you never call? What is `CSkin`? Lots and lots and lots of either missing or irrelevant code. Let me stress this just one last time: A [mcve] needs to be **minimal** and **complete**.

Comment: Those accelerators came with the code generated with the wizard and the cskin I thought it wasn't relevant to the question so I didn't provide it, but if you wish I can provide.The InitInstance was the code that was generated by the wizard and I'm not using it.

Comment: Remove the `case WM_CREATE`. If it was created as part of the template, then your template is corrupted. I would start with a brand new project from a fresh template, verify that the unchanged project works, then gradually add pieces. Once it stops working, then you know that it was the last piece you added that is the problem.

Comment: `//   PURPOSE: Registers the class` - Maybe it [should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa), too?

Comment: IInspectable you were correct I forget  the RegisterClassEx function.

Comment: It works now but my button for some reason doesn't show up.

Comment: You don't seem to do any error checking. And it looks like you have not done any debugging. Consider spending time learning how to debug.

Comment: I know how to debug but doing it in win32 is new to me. Yes, you are correct I didn't do error checking which i'm at fault for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "[Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows)":

> After the CreateWindowEx call, the layered window **will not become
>   visible** until the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` or
>   `UpdateLayeredWindow` function has been called for this window.

The following is an example to make the layered window visible (show up):

```
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_LAYERED, g_szClassName, "Scenes", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL,
       hInstance, NULL);

   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, NULL, 255, LWA_ALPHA);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

**Update:**

Another cause for this issue is `RegisterClassExW` is not called (in `RegisterClass1`), this will cause `CreateWindow` fails with returning `NULL` window handle. So **error checking is very important**.

Comment: The issue was resolved— i was so stupid that I forgot to call the RegisterClass Ex function — but thanks for your input. I did notice this as well that if i don't put the SetLayeredWindowAttributes, that it doesn't come up as  well.

Comment: @Unknownguy But `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` doesn't appear in your question code. I update my answer to add your discovery. Glad to hear you got it working.