# Purpose of WM_CREATE message?

Tags: c++, winapi

What's the point of having the WM_CREATE message when you can create windows without it.

Calling void CreateWindowA outside of WM_CREATE works so what's the deal?

Comment: You can't create windows _with_ it.

Comment: Hopefully you don't destroy windows by posting `WM_DESTROY` messages instead of calling `DestroyWindow` function.

Comment: [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create)?

Comment: What I meant was that the call to CreateWindowA works even without it being in WM_CREATE. Obviously not actually creating windows with it.

Comment: Okay, but you don't get the message until the window is created, so in order to call `CreateWindow` there, you'd need another window already.

Comment: Heed the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293984/c-win32-window-not-showing-up-despite-it-running#comment108433113_61293984) you were given before. You will not understand how the system is designed by guessing.

Comment: @IInspectable I have the book but sometimes it helps if I talk to other programmers to make sure my understanding is correct so no I wasn't guessing.

Comment: @Unknownguy Feel free let me know if you still have concern about `WM_CREATE` message.

Answer (score 10):

`WM_CREATE` message is received by window procedure when window is created and not shown yet. You can prepare initial state. For example, you can create controls (child windows), set default values for controls, etc. If something is wrong, you can cancel creation of window and it will not be shown. In other words, in `WM_CREATE` you can add custom extension to `CreateWindow` API.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why an application could want/need to intercept the `WM_CREATE` message. For example, you may want to check a for a particular condition, and prevent the actual creation if that condition is wrong: you can do this by returning `-1` from the `WndProc` that handles the message ([see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create)):

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero to
>   continue creation of the window. If the application returns –1, the
>   window is destroyed and the **CreateWindowEx** or **CreateWindow** function
>   returns a **NULL** handle.

Comment: Is it good practice then to call the function  CreateWindowA only there or should window creation be done at different places?

Comment: The WM_CREATE handler is the most common place to create child windows but nothing says you have to. For example unless a particular flag is set the property sheet dialog postpones creation of individual page dialogs until the page is actually going to be displayed. (And while CreateWindow is not called by user code in that circumstance CreateDialog and DialogBox calls eventually result in such a call). I've had cases where I used a check-box to flip whether a particular child window was actually created. In win16 days you were much more likely to run into system limits just creating windows.

Comment: You can't call it only there. Because the message won't ever be sent to you until you call CreateWindow.

Comment: @Unknownguy Maybe you have not understood the order - the application calls `CreateWindow` for specific window class, `CreateWindow` prepares the window which is not visible yet and before finishing its work it sends `WM_CREATE` to window class function. If the function want to handle `WM_CREATE`, it can do it. Otherwise the message is ignored and the window is created in default way.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the point of having the WM_CREATE message when you can create
>   windows without it.

If you don't handle **`WM_CREATE`** message explicitly, it is actually handled by system via `DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);` implicitly. So you see the window visible.

**`WM_CREATE`** message is sent before the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function returns, that give you an opportunity to intervene the result of mentioned function. You can **allow** (return zero to continue creation of the window) or **prevent** (returns –1, the window is destroyed) the window to be visible, and how it will looks like.

> The `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE` message are sent before the window
>   becomes visible. That makes them a good place to initialize your
>   UI—for example, to determine the **initial layout of the window**.

Refer to "[Managing Application State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-)", "[WM_CREATE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create)".